# This iPhone ... is running iOS 11.4.1 (15G77), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I tried to run my app on my device in Xcode and I got this error -

```
This iPhone 8 Plus ... is running iOS 11.4.1 (15G77), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode
```

I have macOS 10.12.6 and Xcode 9.1 and Xcode 9.2 but I get the error on both versions.

**How can I still run the app on my device, should I downgrade the IOS or there is another way ?**

Comment: Download device support files and add to xcode

Comment: Xcode's supported iOS version should be __greater than or equal to__ the device's iOS version – iOS 11.4.1 is supported by Xcode9.4+; so download the latest Xcode and you will be a happy panda.

Comment: you can add device support file if some one have latest xcode 9.4. and you can put that support file to your old xcode as PiyushRathi suggest, after that need to force quite xcode and when you attach device with 11.4.1 OS, error will be solve.

Comment: Can I download Xcode 9.4.1 on macOS 10.12.6 ? Is it comlpatible ?

Comment: I am also looking for 11.4.1 (15G77) support files . but cannot find them, did you find a solution for this? Where does one get/extract these files from? Thanks.

Comment: Nope I just download Mac Os High Sierra 10.13.6 and updated Xcode 9.4. And now I can test on my iPhone no problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can download device support files if you don't want to change your Xcode right now from [here](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport)

And then put at a location.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

**But ideally, Xcode update should be done so that you will be on latest track.**

Comment: And btw can I simply download Xcode 9.4 on macOS 10.12.6 ?

Comment: No For this, you have to update Mac OS as well.

Comment: I was unable to simply paste it at that location, so I had to use `sudo mkdir` and `sudo cp` to put the files in the right place. For those who need any help, here's more detail: https://medium.com/@namenotrequired/cannot-paste-into-iphoneos-platform-devicesupport-c3683cd82ed

Answer (score 1):

You have to use at least **Xcode 9.4** for **iOS 11.4.1** devices.

Download and install the latest Xcode to work with **iOS 11.4** device.